# When add react-native component to native ios app, always can not connect to server when run on device

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to add react-native component to the native ios app. I can run on simulator successfully, but when run on device, alway show red error: cannot connect to server.

My app structure is as below:

[image]

[image]

ReactViewController is a view controller that loads the react-native component.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

#if DEBUG
    NSLog(@"AppDelegate:DEBUG");

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    NSLog(@"AppDelegate:DEBUG:TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR");
    jsCodeLocation = [NSURL      URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];
#else
    NSLog(@"AppDelegate:DEBUG:!TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR");
    NSLog(@"To device debug, open RCTWebSocketExecutor.m & replace localhost with MacBook IP.");
    // Get dev host IP Address:
    //    ifconfig | grep inet\ | tail -1 | cut -d " " -f 2
    jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://19.244.52.152:8081/ReactComponent/index.ios.bundle"];
#endif

#else
    NSLog(@"AppDelegate:RELEASE jsbundle");
    jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif

    RCTRootView * rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                     moduleName:@"FPDemo"
                                              initialProperties:nil
                                                  launchOptions:nil];
    self.view = rootView;
}
```

Comment: Have you also edited `RCTWebSocketExecutor.m`?

Comment: In iOS 9.0+ Apple by default blocks non-secure (http) requests. you have to add this to your Info.plist `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>`

Comment: or Instead of allowing your specific IP address, you can disable the `NSAppTransportSecurity` feature.

`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
</dict>`

Comment: you should look to https://gist.github.com/almost/898a829d5197c69d29b0 and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/304

Comment: @Ashok I've tried your suggestions, still fail.

Comment: And I'v already run 'npm start'

Comment: what version of react-native you are running. with latest version you no need to make any changes. you can directly run

Comment: @Stella Have you tried opening http://19.244.52.152:8081 through your device's browser? Maybe that could give us some clues.

Comment: @version 0.39.2

Comment: @martinarroyo I tried on my device browser, can not connect to the server.

Comment: @Stella Then, either you got the IP wrong, the device is not in the same network as your computer or (given than the packager is assumed to be running) something is blocking the requests. Check your firewall/other security software.